# Android intent open specific twitter in app

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter

There is a way of knowing the id of the specific twitter that you want to open, to be able to open it in the official app.

I remember I found it long ago, but I can not remember.

I think it was a similar thing, but I'm not remembering.

```
   Intent appIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://...?tweet_id=" + id));
    appIntent.setPackage("com.twitter.android");
```

Comment: Would you specify what help do you need?

Answer (score 0):

For launching a twitter user feed:

```
Intent intent = null;
try {
    // get the Twitter app if possible
    this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.twitter.android", 0);
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://user?user_id=USERID"));
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // no Twitter app, revert to browser
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/USERID_OR_PROFILENAME"));
}
this.startActivity(intent);
```